# Backbone Collection fetch not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Hello i have 1 collection and model:

```
var Album = Backbone.Model.extend({
                url: "api/album",

                defaults: {
                    name: ""
                }

            });

var AlbumCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                url: "api/albums",
                model: Album
            });
```

If i try to fetch data from that url like this:

```
  var newCollection = AlbumCollection();
  newCollection.fetch({
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(11)
                    console.log(data)
                }
            })
```

its does not fetch data from that url - models in collection are empty. And in network tab in browser - i see there is not `www.myurl.com/api/albums` - call...

but if if i use jquery get it works:

```
 $.get('api/albums', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            })
```

return valid json.

I cant figure it out, i spent countless hours debuggin this, and searching for a problem, please help.

Comment: You did not instantiate the collection.
Should be var newCollection =  new AlbumCollection();

Answer (score 1):

you missed `new` keyword

```
   var newCollection = new AlbumCollection();
      newCollection.fetch({
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(11)
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                })
```